# Set WebSphere's default application

Tags: websphere, default, ear

So instead of the url `http://myserver.com/` returning me

> SRVE0255E: A WebGroup/Virtual Host to handle /jsp/index.jsp has not been defined.
>   SRVE0255E: A WebGroup/Virtual Host to handle myserver.com:80 has not been defined.

I want it to redirect to the application set at `http://myserver.com/myapp`

It seems to be trying to redirect to `/jsp/index.jsp` already, I just need to change that url...

I did this in WebLogic but having trouble figuring it out in WebSphere.

I tried setting the Context root of the application I want as default to '/'. Which worked in setting it as homepage -- but it's not precisely what I'm looking for and it broke the application in question (probably due to resources it uses).

There HAS to be a nicer way to set my homepage to redirect to the application... It seems like a gross oversight, if there isn't a nice way to set a default, but I can't seem to find it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing in WebSphere as default application redirection. In default installation you have `Default Application` which is mapped to `/` and provides way do validate installation e.g. `snoop` servlet.

You can do one of the following:

- Install YOUR application with the `/` as context root and uninstall or change context root in the `Default Application`
- If you use HTTP server in front, define redirection there
- If you don't have HTTP server or your application doesn't work with `/` context root, you could implement very simple application with one page doing redirect to your primary application
- lastly, but I wouldn't recommend that, you could add that page with redirect to the provided `Default Application` installed.